# Problemas al mandar un email en una aplicacion android studio

Tags: android

Buenas tengo el siguiente codigo, la cosa es que lo copio y lo pego en el intellij y me va perfectamente pero lo implemento en el android studio y no me sale. Adjunto la pila de error que me sale.

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.proyectouno, PID: 22171
    java.lang.VerifyError: Rejecting class com.sun.mail.handlers.text_plain that attempts to sub-type erroneous class com.sun.mail.handlers.handler_base (declaration of 'com.sun.mail.handlers.text_plain' appears in /data/app/~~bIl1Dk5H1Fn-8tgLMsm2HA==/com.example.proyectouno-FlRR8NTY8-4CjrPTVwNy-w==/base.apk)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
        at javax.activation.MailcapCommandMap.getDataContentHandler(MailcapCommandMap.java:600)
        at javax.activation.MailcapCommandMap.createDataContentHandler(MailcapCommandMap.java:554)
        at javax.activation.DataHandler.getDataContentHandler(DataHandler.java:627)
        at javax.activation.DataHandler.writeTo(DataHandler.java:329)
        at javax.mail.internet.MimeUtility.getEncoding(MimeUtility.java:324)
        at javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart.updateHeaders(MimeBodyPart.java:1525)
        at javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage.updateHeaders(MimeMessage.java:2198)
        at javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage.saveChanges(MimeMessage.java:2159)
        at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:123)
        at com.example.proyectouno.AccessControl.send(AccessControl.java:77)
        at com.example.proyectouno.MainActivity$5.onClick(MainActivity.java:137)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7448)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7425)
        at android.view.View.access$3600(View.java:810)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:28305)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
     Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: Verifier rejected class com.sun.mail.handlers.handler_base: java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[] com.sun.mail.handlers.handler_base.getTransferDataFlavors() failed to verify: java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[] com.sun.mail.handlers.handler_base.getTransferDataFlavors(): [0x4]  can't resolve returned type 'Unresolved Reference: java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[]' or 'Reference: javax.activation.ActivationDataFlavor[]' (declaration of 'com.sun.mail.handlers.handler_base' appears in /data/app/~~bIl1Dk5H1Fn-8tgLMsm2HA==/com.example.proyectouno-FlRR8NTY8-4CjrPTVwNy-w==/base.apk)
```

y el codigo que tengo es el siguiente:

```
//Get properties object
        final String username = "user";
        final String password = "password";

        Properties prop = new Properties();
        prop.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
        prop.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");
        prop.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        prop.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
        prop.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");

        Session session = Session.getInstance(prop,
                new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                        return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
                    }
                });

        try {

            Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("Fromemail@gmail.com"));
            message.setRecipients(
                    Message.RecipientType.TO,
                    InternetAddress.parse("Toemail@gmail.com")
            );
            message.setSubject("Testing Gmail SSL");
            message.setText("Dear Mail Crawler,"
                    + "\n\n Please do not spam my email!");

            Transport.send(message);

            System.out.println("Done");

        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

he probado con diferentes puertos y de todo pero no me funciona. Lo que quiero llegar a conseguir es que pulsando un botón se envié un correo. En mi aplicacion estoy utilizando una clase orientado a objetos que es donde guardo el metodo y luego lo llamo en el boton para ejecutar el siguiente codigo, lo que mas curioso me parece es que el error me lo marque cuando se llama a Transport.send(message);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

eso es porque android studio necesita permisos para realizar dichas acciones, debes ir al archivo manifest de tu proyecto y añadir la siguiente línea de código:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Fuera de eso si lo que quieres es enviar el correo directamente sin que el usuario manipule otra aplicación de mensajería, debes agregar 3 librerías en la carpeta lib: additional.jar, activation.jar y mail.jar. en caso de que no las tengas me avisas que te paso el link.

```
public class GmailSender extends javax.mail.Authenticator {
String mailhost = "smtp.gmail.com";
private final String user;
private final String password;
private final Session session;

static {
    Security.addProvider(new JSSEProvider());
}

public GmailSender(String user, String password) {
    this.user = user;
    this.password = password;

    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.setProperty("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
    props.setProperty("mail.host", mailhost);
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class",
            "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false");
    props.setProperty("mail.smtp.quitwait", "false");

    session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, this);
}

protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
    return new PasswordAuthentication(user, password);
}

public synchronized void sendMail(String Texto, String Asunto, String sender, String email) throws Exception {
    try{
        DataHandler handler = new DataHandler(new ByteArrayDataSource(Texto.getBytes(), "Text/plain"));
        MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
        message.setSender(new InternetAddress(sender));
        message.setSubject(Asunto);
        message.setDataHandler(handler);
        if (email.indexOf(',') > 0)
            message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(email));
        else
            message.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(email));
        Transport.send(message);
    }catch(Exception e){
        Log.d("Error", "sendingMailError"+ e.getMessage());
    }
}

public class ByteArrayDataSource implements DataSource {
    private byte[] data;
    private String type;

    public ByteArrayDataSource(byte[] data, String type) {
        super();
        this.data = data;
        this.type = type;
    }

    public ByteArrayDataSource(byte[] data) {
        super();
        this.data = data;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public String getContentType() {
        if (type == null)
            return "application/octet-stream";
        else
            return type;
    }

    public InputStream getInputStream() throws IOException {
        return new ByteArrayInputStream(data);
    }

    public String getName() {
        return "ByteArrayDataSource";
    }

    public OutputStream getOutputStream() throws IOException {
        throw new IOException("Not Supported");
    }
}
```

}

El codigo siguiente es para la clase JSSEProvider:

```
public final class JSSEProvider extends Provider {

public JSSEProvider() {
    super("HarmonyJSSE", 1.0, "Harmony JSSE Provider");
    AccessController.doPrivileged(new java.security.PrivilegedAction<Void>() {
        public Void run() {
            put("SSLContext.TLS",
                    "org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.SSLContextImpl");
            put("Alg.Alias.SSLContext.TLSv1", "TLS");
            put("KeyManagerFactory.X509",
                    "org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.KeyManagerFactoryImpl");
            put("TrustManagerFactory.X509",
                    "org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.TrustManagerFactoryImpl");
            return null;
        }
    });
}
```

}

Y en la clase que corresponde a la activity donde esta hecho el formulario de enviar mensaje, copia esto en la parte de arriba antes de onCreate:

```
String user= "aqui pones la direccion desde donde vas a enviar los correos";
String password = "contraseña de la direccion anterior";
```

Y copia esto despues de donde has refenciado cada textview y boton(es)

```
sender = new GmailSender(user, password);
    button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
            Nombre = txtv1.getText().toString();
            Correo = txtv2.getText().toString();
            Asunto = txtv3.getText().toString();
            Texto = txtmulti1.getText().toString();

            new MyAsyncClass().execute();
        }
    });
}

@SuppressLint("StaticFieldLeak")
class MyAsyncClass extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    ProgressDialog pDialog;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {

        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity8.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Por favor espere...");
        pDialog.show();

    }

    @Override

    protected Void doInBackground(Void... mApi) {
        try {

            // Add subject, Body, your mail Id, and receiver mail Id.
            sender.sendMail(Texto, Asunto, user, email);
            Log.d("send", "done");
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            Log.d("exceptionsending", ex.toString());
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override

    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

        super.onPostExecute(result);
        pDialog.cancel();

        Toast.makeText(MainActivity8.this, "Correo enviado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
}
```

}

Saludos!

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116555/discussion-on-answer-by-rixos-problemas-al-mandar-un-email-en-una-aplicacion-and).